# What are the benefits of an indexer?

Tags: c#, indexer

Can somebody explain what is the benefit of having an indexer?

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<string> list = new List<string>()

    public string this[int value]
    {
         get 
         {
             return list[value];
         }
     }

     public string GetValue(int value)
     {
          return list[value];
     }
}
```

What is the benefit of using:

```
MyClass target = new MyClass();
string value = target[0];
```

over this:

```
MyClass target = new MyClass();
string value = target.GetValue(0);
```

Comment: You dont need to write `GetValue` and you know that the class is a collection with an indexer but you might lose readability because the indexer has no name, so don't misuse it.

Comment: It's a *syntax sugar*, the advantage is *readability*

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: readability isnt the benefit, the opposite can be true because the indexer has no name

Comment: Exactly like what @DmitryBychenko said, it is actually just a syntactic sugar

Comment: My rule of thumb would be: If your class is basically just a collection (or wrapping one), use an indexer. ```names[0]``` is easily understood as 'the first name in a collection of names'. If the call-site cannot be read like that I'd avoid creating an indexer. YMMV

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is purely syntactic convenience and readability / expressiveness. It is still implemented as a method. So: if you think `target[0]` is more obvious, convenient and readable for your scenario: use an indexer.